# IMacros: How to use Prompt with javascript

Tags: javascript, prompt, imacros

Ok so in a code below you can see that i have to put Page and Search in quotation marks, but then `javascript` "thinks" that i'm closing quotation mark that is before **PROMPT**.

**Anyone knows what should i do with it?**

```
var macro;
macro = "CODE:";
macro += "PROMPT "Page" !VAR1" + "\n";
macro += "PROMPT "Search" !VAR2" + "\n";
macro += "TAB OPEN" + "\n";
macro += "TAB T=2" + "\n";
macro += "URL GOTO=https://{{!VAR1}}" + "\n";
macro += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro += "SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 3" + "\n";
macro += "SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 3" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:masthead-search ATTR=ID:masthead-search-term CONTENT={{!VAR2}}" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:masthead-search ATTR=ID:search-btn" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:gbqf ATTR=ID:gbqfq CONTENT={{!VAR2}}" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:gbqf ATTR=ID:gbqfb" + "\n";
macro += "SET !ERRORIGNORE NO" + "\n";
macro += "SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 60" + "\n";
macro += "SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 60" + "\n";
iimPlay(macro);
```

**Additional info:**

- I'm using Windows 7 and firefox for this macro.
- I want it to be in javascript because i will add some loops later

Sorry for mistakes, English isn't my mother language.

Comment: Write down your lines with 'PROMPT' in such manner: `macro += 'PROMPT "Page" !VAR1' + "\n";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var x='PROMPT \"Page\" ';
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x ;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Check the code and adjust according to that